# CSS Borders: Distance from Object Edge?

Tags: css, position, border

Quick question. I was writing out some code and was curious if there is a way to add a border on a div that is 5px within the object - as in not on the actual edge of the div. I checked out WC3 and didn't see any specs - but I may have missed it.

In my case I'd be using a dashed border 5px inside the div, to create an effect like the div had been sewn to the rest of the site. I can do it fairly easily with background-image but why add KB when a line or two of css could do it.

I would assume it would be something like "border-position" or "border-distance".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never come across any property that resembles this, so I'd have to say, simply, 'no.'

But then I'd feel bad for that, so all I could really suggest is wrapping the `div` you wish to 'sew on' within another `div` and styling the parent with the same `background-color` to emulate the look you're after. Here's some css for a possible take:

```
.wrap {
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #ffa;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.wrap #panel {
    background-color: inherit;
    height: 6em;
    border: 5px dashed #f90;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And some html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="panel">
        <p>This panel should look kinda sewn-on.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, finally, [A JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GxEZH/)

Okay, having just rediscovered this answer (thanks to the up-voter!), I can, now, provide an actual CSS-only no-extraneous-elements solution, using `box-shadow`:

```
#panel {
    background-color: #ffa;
    height: 6em;
    border: 5px dashed #f90;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #ffa;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GxEZH/35/).

The fourth parameter is the key, it defines the, uh, 'spread' of the shadow (the third parameter defines the 'fuzziness'/'diffusion' which in this case is `0`), using the same `background-color` as the element itself gives the illusion that the `border` is within the element, while it's actually a shadow of the element extending out *from* the element.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I hadn't seen it either - but thought it was worth asking. The div wrap sounds like a viable solution.

Comment: This helped me fix a display issue for an iPad application where random box lines of various colours were appearing around divs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thats what IE used to do in quirks mode. With CSS3 `box-sizing` you can switch between the two modes, but I'm not sure how the support is at the moment
See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html for more infos.