# change color of bottom boundary upto certain range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to change the color of bottom boundary of a div up-to certain distance or range (i.e. not complete bottom border). I am using the following code but it will change the color of complete bottom:

```
style.borderBottom = "2px solid blue";
```

Comment: Don't believe there is.  You will most likely need to use an image to do this.  However, I could be wrong.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068650/css-borders-distance-from-object-edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an extra element and style it with css:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHMeW/