# Possible to reduce white-space between span/in-line element content and its border?

Tags: html, css

I've got some inline text marked-up as a span. I've given the span a bottom dashed border (to differentiate it from a hyperlink), but the distance between the span content and the border is a bit too much. Is there a way to reduce it?

I've tried zeroing/negativing (totally should be a word) the margins/paddings as well as reducing the line-height for the element with no luck. Granted, reducing the line-height for an inline span probably shouldn't work.

#### CSS

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

span.test {
    color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed orange;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JxmEu/)

Comment: This probably solves your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068650/css-borders-distance-from-object-edge

Comment: That was a rather... extensive solution to the issue. The folks below have a MUCH better solution for my needs. Thanks for checking that out though! I tried searching SO for an answer and couldn't find one that suited my needs as well as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to do it with a combination of using `display: inline-block;` and `line-height: 1em;`

Of course, if you need it less than that, reduce the line height.

http://jsfiddle.net/JxmEu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change the display of `.test` to `inline-block`.  Then, you can alter its `line-height`.  Reducing the `line-height` will move the border up without affecting the font size or text around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/JxmEu/2/

Comment: Yes, this is what worked. I accepted David's answer because he seemed to be first, but +1. Thanks for taking time to look :)